# pass a function as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently solving an exercise and I am facing a problem passing a funcion as an argument to another function.
The exercise is:
1.Declare a function which takes two arguments, **a** and **b**, and returns the sum of those arguments. 
`var add = function(a,b){return a+b;};`

2.Declare the variable **calculator** and assign it a function which takes three arguments, **a,b and c**. Inside the body of **calculator**, invoke the function passed as the argument **c**, passing as arguments **a** and **b**.       `var calculator = function(a,b,c=add(a,b))
{ var invoke = c;
   console.log(invoke);  };`

3.invoke calculate passing it the **sum** function as a third argument.
   Is it supposed to be like this?    `calculate(x,y,sum());`

when the code is submitted I get the following error: The function calculate should print the result of calling undefined with x and y as arguments;

Can anyone help ?

Comment: By putting parenthesis here `sum()`, you are actually calling the function and passing its result as a parameter

Comment: You should write it like this `calculate(x,y,sum);`. As @Guerric said, sum() is invoking the function, evaluating it in place. You want the variable that contains the function, which is `sum`, to be passed as an argument to `calculate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

"Invoke the function c passing as arguments a and b" is a lot of words for `c(a,b)`

It sounds like the result from the second step should look like:

```
var calculator = function(a,b,c) { return c(a,b) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what's "first class functions". Practically that says that functions are values like everything.

There is a huge different between `var a = f()` and `var a = f`. The former **invokes**, or **runs**, `f` and saves the result in `a`. The later saves **`f` itself** in `a`. That means that `a` is a function, and you can do `a()` - which is equal to `f()`.

If you want to create a function that takes another function as argument (the new function is called *higher order function*, and the existing one is a *callback*), you do it as follows:

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function calculator(a, b, callback) {
  return callback(a, b); // Invoke the function stored in `callback` with parameters `a` and `b` and return the result
}
```

Now I leave the third part for you as an exercise...

#### Edit:

As of ES6, you can define default parameter of the form `function(param = default)`, however in order to use `add` as default value, you should make sure you declare it before `calculate` so when the js engine see `calculate`'s declaration it already knows what is `add`.

Comment: `var add = function(a, b){
    return a+b; 
};

var calculate = function(a,b,c= add){
    var operate = c(a,b);
   console.log(c(a,b));
   
};
calculate(1,5);`//prints the correct result. however, now the error is:
>>>>Code is incorrect
The function calculate should print the result of calling undefined with a and b as arguments

Comment: I am sorry for the basic question but I am still beggining to code in JS

Comment: Why do you call `c` twice?